# Cannot scrape specific table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a bit new to webscraping and wanted to scrape few HTML tables using BeautifulSoup in Python. The webpage is https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/keepers/Premier-League-Stats. As you will see there are two tables "Squad Goalkeeping" and "Player Goalkeeping".

Using the following code I am able to capture both tables.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re


url = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/keepers/Premier-League-Stats'
html_content = requests.get(url).text

bs = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"lxml")
gk_stats = bs.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"table_wrapper"})
```

gk_stats contains 2 elements "Squad Goalkeeping" and "Player Goalkeeping", which I can see by indexing gk_stats[0] and gk_stats[1], respectively. However, when I try to find the "tr" tag in "Player Goalkeeping" it gives me an empty list.

```
gk_stats[1].find_all("tr")
```

Could anybody please explain to me why I cannot extract the table even though I have it as a BeautifulSoup element? I can also see the table when I inspect the element in Chrome browser.

I am able to extract "Squad Goalkeeping" table using the same command but with index 0 `gk_stats[0].find_all("tr")`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you fetched the page and looked at it?  In the page as delivered, the `table_wrapper` divs contain nothing.  All of the content you see is fill in dynamically using Javascript.

Comment: It looks like the first table (squad goalkeeping) is baked into the HTML, so beautifulsoup should be able to see it. The second table (player goalkeeping), however, is not directly baked into the HTML. When viewed in a browser, this page populates some of the elements in the DOM asynchronously using JavaScript, and one of those elements happens to be the second table, for whatever reason. This, of course, beautifulsoup cannot see. However, a cursory inspection reveals that the **contents** of the second table are baked into the HTML, just in comments. You'll have to parse the HTML manually.

Comment: Hi Tim an Paul. Thank you for the input.I didn't know it was included through JavaScript, still relatively new to these concepts. Though, I have looked up some material on webscraping on Javascript pages and would be next on my list to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the table is commented. A quick fix is to remove `<!--` and `-->` from the html code. Also, you can load html tables directly into pandas with `read_html` (no need for BeautifulSoup):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/keepers/Premier-League-Stats'
html_content = requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')
df = pd.read_html(html_content)
```

`read_html` will return a list of tables as dataframes, which can be accessed with `df[0]`, `df[1]` etc.
Player goalkeeping is in `df[2]`. Let's remove the top header row and the mid-table header rows:

```
df[2].columns = df[2].columns.droplevel(0) # drop top header row
df[2] = df[2][df[2]['Rk'].ne('Rk')].reset_index() # remove mid-table header rows
```

Output `df[2]`:

|  | index | Rk | Player | Nation | Pos | Squad | Age | Born | MP | Starts | Min | 90s | GA | GA90 | SoTA | Saves | Save% | W | D | L | CS | CS% | PKatt | PKA | PKsv | PKm | Save% | Matches |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | Adrián | es ESP | GK | Liverpool | 34-068 | 1987 | 3 | 3 | 270 | 3 | 9 | 3 | 19 | 10 | 52.6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 33.3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | nan | Matches |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | Rúnar Alex Rúnarsson | is ISL | GK | Arsenal | 26-022 | 1995 | 1 | 0 | 16 | 0.2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | nan | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | nan | Matches |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | Alisson | br BRA | GK | Liverpool | 28-161 | 1992 | 23 | 23 | 2070 | 23 | 26 | 1.13 | 73 | 50 | 69.9 | 10 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 21.7 | 8 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 20 | Matches |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | Alphonse Areola | fr FRA | GK | Fulham | 28-013 | 1993 | 27 | 27 | 2430 | 27 | 30 | 1.11 | 113 | 88 | 77.9 | 5 | 11 | 11 | 9 | 33.3 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Matches |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | Kepa Arrizabalaga | es ESP | GK | Chelsea | 26-160 | 1994 | 4 | 4 | 360 | 4 | 6 | 1.5 | 18 | 12 | 66.7 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | nan | Matches |

Comment: Thank you! Removing the  <!-- and --> works well. The reason for not importing this table straight into pandas was to learn how to scrape and then develop a crawler. I am still new to web scraping and wanted to get my hands on with it. I appreciate your input. Thanks again.